# Problems with installing pycryptodome

Tags: apt, python, pip

I have modified my thinkpad's BIOS to remove the wifi whitelist and plan to flash the modified bios back to the eeprom. To do that I have to use a tool called [thinkpad-uefi-sign](https://github.com/thrimbor/thinkpad-uefi-sign) which signs the image so it can boot. Thinkpad-uefi-sign requires using pycryptodome. I installed that using

```
apt install python3-pycryptodome
```

However it still didn't work and have the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

when I run thinkpad-uefi-sign/verify.py. I am using Debian Testing Trixie with up to date packages and Python 3.11.5.

Another thing I tried was to install it using

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

however that gave a warning that it could break packages and to install it instead using apt install python-xyz. I then installed python3-full and set up a venv (virtual environment) using python3 -m venv /path/to/venv. I installed pycryptodome in the venv using

```
/path/to/venv/bin/pip3 install pycryptodome
```

I then ran the script thinkpad-uefi-sign/verify.py with

```
/path/to/venv/bin/python3 thinkpad-uefi-sign/verify.py Bios_Modded.bin
```

and still ran into the same error. After that I tried installing pycryptodomex, Crypto, and pycrypto using pip3 from the venv but still ran into the error when running the program. I additionally tried to try the answers from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824628/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-crypto-error), but it didn't help much.
I also tried using a macbook and it seemed to work there for some reason so it might be a packaging-related issue.
Encase this could be helpful, this is the command and the full output.

```
$ ./python3_venv_with_pycryptodome/bin/python3 thinkpad-uefi-sign/verify.py Bios_Modded.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/witherslayer/Sowa/ThkpX1CG2_UEFIs/workflow/thinkpad-uefi-sign/verify.py", line 19, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Comment: `apt install` will install it for the default system python, but not for a virtual env. You will have to activate the venv, then install the library in there with `pip` . Also, you are not working with venvs correctly - you should **not** call those paths directly! `activate` the venv instead!

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it to work after activating it with the instructions from [here] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the signing software after activating the python venv as stated from Panki's comment. I did that for bash using the command

```
$ source <venv>/bin/activate
```

from the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 0):

This library has a feature since 3.4.1:

> 3.4.1 (21 February 2016)
>
> New features
>
> - Added option to install the library under the `Cryptodome` package (instead of `Crypto`).

And indeed that's needed to avoid a conflict with the old PyCrypto library if both are installed or used at the same time, as documented in the sources:

[either](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/v3.11.0/INSTALL.rst?plain=1#L7):

> An almost drop-in replacement for the old PyCrypto library.
>
> ```
> You install it with::
>
> pip install pycryptodome
> In this case, all modules are installed under the `Crypto` package. You can test everything is right with::
>   
> pip install pycryptodome-test-vectors
> python -m Crypto.SelfTest
> ```
>
> **One must avoid having both PyCrypto and PyCryptodome** installed at the
> same time, as they will interfere with each other. This option is
> therefore recommended only when you are sure that the whole
> application is deployed in a `virtualenv`.

[or](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/v3.11.0/INSTALL.rst?plain=1#L23):

> library independent of the old PyCrypto.
>
> You install it with::
>
> ```
> pip install pycryptodomex
> You can test everything is right with::
>
> pip install pycryptodome-test-vectors
> python -m Cryptodome.SelfTest
> ```
>
> In this case, **all modules are installed under the `Cryptodome` package.
> The old PyCrypto and PyCryptodome can coexist.**

Debian as a a distributor chose this option to avoid any potential clash (even if it doesn't provide the old PyCrypto at all):

[`debian/rules`](https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/packages/pycryptodome/-/blob/debian/3.11.0+dfsg1-4/debian/rules#L18):

> ```
> touch .separate_namespace
> ```

[`setup.py`](https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/packages/pycryptodome/-/blob/debian/3.11.0+dfsg1-4/setup.py#L42):

> ```py
> use_separate_namespace = os.path.isfile(".separate_namespace")
> ```

> ```py
> other_project = "pycryptodomex"
> other_root = "Cryptodome"
> ```

> ```py
> if use_separate_namespace:
>     project_name, other_project = other_project, project_name
>     package_root, other_root = other_root, package_root
> ```

In the end it's also possible to use Debian's packaged library (without venv): replace `Crypto` with `Cryptodome` in [`sign.py`](https://github.com/thrimbor/thinkpad-uefi-sign/blob/master/sign.py#L18) and [`verify.py`](https://github.com/thrimbor/thinkpad-uefi-sign/blob/master/verify.py#L19).